AppleScript/Shortcuts Question
I would like to create two shortcuts:
The first should be a shortcut that copies a file from one folder (duplicate, not cut) and pastes it in another.
The second one should be able to delete the pasted file from the new folder and then clear trash along with that. BTW, the file is an app if it changes anything.
I want to do all of this in the Shortcuts app on my M2 Mac. I noticed that you can put AppleScript directly into the Shortcuts app without Script Editor, so that's great. I don't mind whether the shortcut is using the Shortcut app elements or AppleScript.

Applications on mac are just directories.
You don't need Applescript for either of these.
The copy one is easy:

All you have to do is change cLion to the app you want and applications to the folder you want.
To delete, assuming the file is the same every time, you can just do this:
The delete immediately skips the recycle bin and fully deletes it.
You won't be able to carry a variable that contains the file across both shortcuts, but you can handle the inputs with a set variable at the beginning of the script.
To chain these together, make a third shortcut that prompts to ask you which choice you want,  calls and passes an input to either of the above shortcuts.
